# Locations and files looked up in an ASP.NET MVC project while searching for a javascript function called from a .cshtml file

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

When a .cshtml file calls up a javascript function using onclick event, which all locations and files does the framework look it up in, apart from the explicit js file reference given using a 'script tag'?

I have a javascript function call being made using an onclick event as following (inside a cshtml file):

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-blue" onclick="SaveContract('@ViewBag.ControlGuid','@ViewBag.PopupContainerId','@ViewBag.RefreshTargetId', '@ViewBag.PopupDivId' )">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-save"></i>
                    @ResourceHelper.GetResourceValue(ResourceId.Save)
                </a>
```

The javascript file reference that is given in the  tag is as following:-

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Contracts/ContractModel.js"></script>
```

However the function SaveContract() was not found inside ContractModel.js but inside another file DefaultScripts.js.

The call is happening perfectly and application is working fine.

My doubt is that when i need to look up in my solution for this function, how can i logically look up for this function instead of doing a blind 'Search in entire solution' of the function name.

To put in other words, how does the framework decide that apart from the explicit javascript file mentioned in the 'script tag', which other files does it need to check to call that function?

Comment: There is no "framework" that decides this, it's just how Javascript works. It has nothing to do with MVC. The Javascript engine will just call the *last* one that was defined.

Comment: So do you mean the function can be anywhere inside the project directory and the javascript engine will look it (function) up everywhere (all .js files)?

Comment: You still need to include the JS file in a `script` tag.